# Prove that for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, $(x+y)(\frac1x+\frac1y)\ge4$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$,
$(x+y)(\frac1x+\frac1y)\ge4$.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried expanding the left side but I do not know how to show that the left sider is also greater than 4, only equal to.

Comment: Use $AM \geq HM$

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
(x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right) = 2 + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}
\end{align*}

According to the inequality $AM\geq GM$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}\cdot\frac{y}{x}} = 2
\end{align*}

from whence we obtain the claimed result.

**EDIT**

Due to JavaMan's observation, I provide you another approach to solve the second part. Indeed, for any $a\in\textbf{R}_{>0}$, we have

$$(a-1)^{2}\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow a^{2} - 2a + 1 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow a^{2} + 1 \geq 2a\Leftrightarrow a + \frac{1}{a} \geq 2$$

In the present case, it suffices to take $a = x/y$.

Comment: AM-GM is too much here.  Simple algebra will do it.

Comment: If you take a=x/y, doesn't the rhs still remain as 2?

Comment: Don't forget to add the previous result:

$$(x+y)\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right)  = 2 + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \geq 2 + 2 = 4$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(x + y)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right)\geq 4 \iff (x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right) xy \geq 4xy$$

Comment: Why is it necessary to multiply by xy here?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it does cancel the fractions.  It turns the equality into $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$ which is equivalent to $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$, which is obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz gives
$$(x+y)(\frac1x+\frac1y)= \left( \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{y}\right)^2 \right)\left( \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2} + \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)^2} \right)\ge \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y}}\right)^2 = 4$$